# Section spacing + border radius

Tags: html, css

I realized as a project to display orders that come from a database.
I display its data in a table format
The problem is that I would like there to be a space between each command in order to make some choqes to better oragnize

I have used the margin bottom in css but nothing works
Also I insert a border radius in order to round the background color but no result appears

RESULT :

[image: 1]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/prepa.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,700,1,200" />
</head>
<body>
        <?php
                $sql = "SELECT enc_id, enc_cmd_num, enc_paye, enc_prepared, enc_ext_ref, enc_heure_fab_deb, enc_type, enc_heure_fab_fin, Client.cli_civilite,Client.cli_nom, Client.cli_prenom FROM Client RIGHT JOIN encaissement ON Client.cli_id = encaissement.enc_client WHERE enc_etat<>4 AND enc_date= '20230113' AND ((DATEDIFF(n,enc_heure_fab_fin, getDate()) < 3 AND enc_prepared <> 0) OR enc_prepared = 0) AND enc_emporte <> 1 ORDER BY encaissement.enc_heure_fab_deb ASC";

                $results = odbc_exec( $conn, $sql );
        ?>

<div class="TABLELEFT">
        <table>
            <?php
                while( $row = odbc_fetch_array( $results ) )
                {
                    printf('<tr>');

                    if ( $row["enc_ext_ref"] != '')
                        {
                            $num_cmd = $row["enc_ext_ref"];
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            $num_cmd =$row["enc_cmd_num"];
                        }


                    if ($row['enc_paye'] = 0)
                    {
                        $etat_cmd='&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<span class="PRETE">ATTENTE REGLEMENT</span></br>';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        switch( $row['enc_prepared'] )
                        {
                            case 0: $etat_cmd='&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<span class="ENPREPA">EN PREPARATION</span><br>'; break;

                            case 1: $etat_cmd='&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<span class="PRETE">COMMANDE PRETE</span></br>'; break;
                        }
                    }

                    switch( $row['enc_type'] )
                    {
                        case 0: $commande='&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<span class="EMPORTER"><img src="img/emporter.png" id="EMP"></img></span>&nbsp</br>'; break;

                        case 1: $commande='&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<span class="LIVRAISON"><img src="img/livreur.png" id="LIV"></img></span>&nbsp<br>'; break;

                        case 2: $commande='&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<span class="SURPLACE"><img src="img/table1.png" id="TABLE"></img></span>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<br>'; break;
                    }

                    printf('<td>%s</td>',$row["enc_cmd_num"],$etat_cmd);

                    printf('<td>%s</td>',$etat_cmd);
                    printf('<td>%s</td>',$commande);
                
                }

            ?>
            </table>
        </div>

   </body>
</html>



-------------------
#TABLE{
width : 100px;
height : 70px;
color: pink;
}

#EMP{
width : 70px;
height : 70px;
}

#LIV{
width : 70px;
height : 70px;
}

table tr {
border: none;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
 table tr.slide-out {
transform: translateX(100%);

}



tr,th,td{
    padding: 0;
    border-spacing: 0;
        background-color: #181818;
        border: none;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
 }


.ENPREPA{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    color: #FF8C01;
}

.PRETE{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    color:#05750D;
    animation-duration: .6s;
    animation-name: clignoter;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    transition: none;
}

@keyframes clignoter {
  0%   { color:#000000; }
  40%   {color:#F1A200; }
  100% { opacity:#000000; }
}


li{
  color: #EB0000;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 20px;

}


.ATTENTE{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';

}

.PAYE{
font-family: 'Montserrat';
font-weight: bold;
color: #11C306;
font-family: 'Montserrat';
}

table{
color: red;
font-family: 'Montserrat';
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: bold;
margin-bottom: 10px;

}

.TABLELEFT{
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}


table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}
```

Comment: You have to select classes in CSS via .<class-name> and #<id> is used for ids

Answer (score 0):

To adjust cell spacing in HTML tables you can play mostly with two properties:

- `border-spacing` sets the distance between rows and columns
- `padding` works only with `td`

```css
table {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  
  border-spacing: 5px;
  
  border-radius: 10px;
}

tr:not(:first-child) td {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>command1</td>
    <td>image1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>command2</td>
    <td>image2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>command3</td>
    <td>image3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```